# CanvasJs chart don't fit its container until browser resize

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, yii2

I am trying since yesterday to create a chart using **Canvasjs**, but when the page is loaded, the chart does not fit its container until i resize the browser. I think the problem could be the order of different javascript files i am using, but i have tried with different ways without success.

Here is the AppAsset file:

```
 public $css = [
    'css/bootstrap.css',
    'css/site.css',
    'highlightJs/styles/magula.css',
    'sweetAlert/sweetalert.css',
    'chart/jquery-ui.min.css',
];

public $js = [
    'highlightJs/highlight.pack.js', 
    'js/main.js',
    'redactorPlugins/imagelink.js',
    'sweetAlert/sweetalert.min.js',
    'chart/jquery.canvasjs.min.js',
    'chart/jquery-ui.min.js',
];

public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];

// render all the Javascripts files in the head of the page   
public $jsOptions = [
'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
];
```

Here is the way I render the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

//Better to construct options first and then pass it as a parameter
var options1 = {
    title: {
        text: "Your Profile's view of last week"
    },
            animationEnabled: true,
    data: [
    {
    type: "spline",
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "Monday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileMondayLastWeek']; ?> },
            { label: "Tuesday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileTuesdayLastWeek']; ?> },
            { label: "Wednesday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileWednesdayLastWeek']; ?> },
            { label: "Thursday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileThursdayLastWeek']; ?> },
            { label: "Friday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileFridayLastWeek']; ?> },
            { label: "Saturday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileSaturdayLastWeek']; ?> },
            { label: "Sunday", y: <?php echo $dataStatistics['viewProfileSundayLastWeek']; ?> }
        ]
    }
    ],
  axisX: {
    labelFontSize: 16
  },
     axisY: {
    labelFontSize: 16
  }
};

$("#tabs").tabs({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        //Render Charts after tabs have been created.
        $("#chartContainer1").CanvasJSChart(options1);
    },

    //**** I don t understand why this is not called during the page loading *****//
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        //Updates the chart to its container's size if it has changed.
        ui.newPanel.children().first().CanvasJSChart().render();
    }
});

});

</script>



<div id="tabs" style="height: 315px">
<ul>
    <li ><a href="#tabs-1" style="font-size: 12px">Last Week</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1" style="height: 240px">
    <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 240px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is also the order how the javascript files are called:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

CanvasJS Chart automatically sets the height and width of the chart according to container’s dimensions. If the values are not set for the container, it takes the default values.

In bootstrap, since the tab is not shown initially, chart takes the default values. To solve this issue, chart should rendered when the shown.bs.tab event is fired by bootstrap.

```js
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      title:{
       text:"Chart 1"
      },  
      data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55},
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });
  chart.render();

  function chartTab2() {
    var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
      title:{
       text:"Chart 2"
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 58 },
        { x: 20, y: 35},
        { x: 30, y: 36 },
        { x: 40, y: 75 },
        { x: 50, y: 45 },
        { x: 60, y: 28 },
        { x: 70, y: 48 },
        { x: 80, y: 14 },
        { x: 90, y: 54}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });
    chart1.render();
  }

$('#bs-tab2').on("shown.bs.tab",function(){
      chartTab2();
      $('#bs-tab2').off(); // to remove the binded event after the initial rendering
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-jt">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Chart 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" id= "bs-tab2" href="#tab2">Chart 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
                <div id="chartContainer1" style=" height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue where the table set for display:none, causing problems until the screen size changes.I fix my problem with using jQuery. I now generate a CanvasJS Chart by clicking on a specific element, like a trigger associated with a table.

basicly like below

```
  $('whatEverYoutriggerForYourTable').on('click', function() {
     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart  <-- hit it here
    });
```

and it works like a charm
.